# VB.NET: Illegible text file

Tags: vb.net, file, text

How can i illegible and save my text file and then read it.
I use this the code below, but this code just work with numbers and i can't save and read string.

Write:

```
Dim FileStr As New FileStream("C:\Text.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
Dim BinWrt As New BinaryWriter(FileStr)
BinWrt.Write(CInt(123456))
BinWrt.Close()
FileStr.Close()
```

Read:

```
Dim FileStr As New FileStream("C:\Text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim BinWrt As New BinaryReader(FileStr)
MessageBox.Show(BinWrt.ReadInt32)
BinWrt.Close()
FileStr.Close()
```

Comment: So you want to obfuscate your strings?

Comment: Use `ReadString` instead of `ReadInt32`?  It's not really clear what you're asking or what isn't working.  Side note: Naming a `BinaryReader` variable `BinWrt` is *probably* a bit misleading.